# Output message at the end of Webpack watch compilation (after warnings and errors)

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use Webpack + fable-loader together with Visual Studio Code tasks so it can highlight warnings and errors directly in the IDE. It's working fine for one-go builds, but not so well in watch compilations. This is because VS Code task configuration requires [both start and end patterns of a watch compilation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_background-watching-tasks) in the tool output. However I cannot get Webpack to output a message at the end of a compilation after all warnings and errors. I've tried using an `after-compile` plugin, but the message appears before the warnings/errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack latest version (2.6.1) now outputs one message at the start and the end of recompilations, so this is not an issue anymore :)